# Give a push down Automata for this language: the length of is odd and it's middle symbol is 0

Tags: automata

Give a push down automaton for this language:

```
{w| the length of w is odd and it's middle symbol is 0}
```

Here is the CFG I wrote for this language:

```
S --> 0|0S0|0s1|1s0|1s1
```

This what I have done for odd length part (I'm not using a stack for first part but I'm sure I need to use stack for second part):

[image]

I've spent days on this question but no luck,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Broad Hint:** You shouldn't have to check that the string has odd length. Note that a string $w$ is in the language $L$ described above iff there is an occurrence of the symbol $\mathtt{0}$ in $w$ such that there are exactly as many symbols in $w$ appearing before that occurrence of $\mathtt{0}$ as there are after.  (For a hint that is a bit more direct, whenever you read a $\mathtt{0}$ from the string non-deterministically guess that this is the correct one, using the stack to check whether the above property holds.)

Comment: What goes down must come up, so to speak.

Comment: Is this correct? http://s22.postimg.org/ipf9p6hhd/Untitled.png instead of 1 in the middle it should be 0

Comment: @Hooman: Not quite.  The PDA described in the image accepts all odd-length _palindromes_ with a $\mathtt{1}$ in the middle (or a $\mathtt{0}$ in the middle if you switch that middle $\mathtt{1}$ to a $\mathtt{0}$).  But it can be modified to give you a solution.  In particular, when you are pushing symbols onto the stack, you are only interested in the _number_ of symbols you have read, not the _type_ of symbols.  (Also, the last transition should be $\varepsilon, \mathtt{\$} \rightarrow \varepsilon$.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Here is the latest edition:http://s18.postimg.org/9mj16e16h/Untitled.png

Comment: @Hooman: The last version looks good to me!

Comment: The thing I love about this website is actually I learn something not just getting the answer. Thank you so much.